# Finding all occurrences of a data in several sets

Tags: c++

I have several `std::multiset`'s that contains some `Point`s (a data structure for holding a pair like (x, y)). Each point may be in several `multiset`s. I need to determine all occurrences of these `Point`s in my `multiset`s. To be clear, for each `Point` I want to know that which `multiset`s contains this `Point` in them. in order to do that I thought maybe for each `Point` I could save a `set` that contains the pointers to the `multiset`s that `Point` is in them. Is this a good Idea?

My code looks like this:

```
static struct Point{
public:
    double x, y;
    std::set<std::multiset<Point>*,PointerCompare>occurrences;

    Point(double a, double b){ x = a; y = b; }
    Point(){}
};

struct PointerCompare{
    bool operator()(std::multiset<Point>* a, std::multiset<Point>* b){
        uintptr_t aVal = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(a);
        uintptr_t bVal = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(b);
        return a < b;
    }
};
```

This code compiles well, but I get run-time error. Am I comparing two pointers right?

Comment: If you have problems with code, it would be a good idea to isolate that problem, i.e. create a minimal but complete example. Also, things like the complete error message would be beneficial. That said, raw pointers are always dangerous, so I'd rather avoid them. Also, remember that containers sometimes copy their elements, so every `Point` is in at most one multiset, even if other instances with the same value exist in other multisets.

Comment: As you need to have control over those `std::multiset`s anyway, what keeps you from performing extra book-keeping when you insert `Point`s into them?

Comment: @ChristianHackl The complexity is important for me, I could use std::map<Point,pointer_to_data>, but it takes log(n) to find my point and then insert its corresponding pointer. I can use some extra memory, But time complexity is very important for me.

Comment: @MoNo: Your idea is good, structure implementation and comparision function are correct. Probably, run-time error has other source.