# How to convert integers to pointers and vice versa

Tags: c++

Suppose that there is a `std::multiset<some_data_type> s`, how can I save the address of this`std::multiset` in to an integer and then use this integer to assign other pointers to its location? I mean is it possible to do something like this:

```
std::multiset<int> mySet; 
//insert some data in mySet
int a = address_of(mySet);
std::multiset<int>* otherSet = location(a);
```

Comment: Why?​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: Why not using iterators ?

Comment: Can't you just use pointers?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? What you are asking for seems bizarre and dangerous.

Comment: On most 64-bit systems the `int` type is still 32 bits, so would break such hacks.

Comment: Also, I think you need to tell us the root problem you are trying to solve, instead of asking us to help with your solution to this unknown problem. Related reading: [What is the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: This (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31641170/finding-all-occurrences-of-a-data-in-several-sets) is my problem, I know how to do this in proper way, But I have to change a huge part of my code, I thought maybe I can use this method if its not dangerous.

Comment: Ehm.... in that question you already use the solution. So, uhm... what?!

Comment: Finally, while using e.g. `intptr_t` is a possible solution, it's a hackish solution and a workaround of what I (and probably others as well) would consider a bad design or code (also known as *design smell* and *code smell*).

Comment: I don't understand the downvote, just because my idea of using integers is not good, it does not mean that my question is not good!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This is what C++11's `intptr_t` type gives you from [`<cstdint>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer)**, if your system supports it (which the standard does not mandate).

If it's available, it's guaranteed to be large enough to hold any pointer value (unlike `int`), and is defined such that converting to and from `intptr_t` and *the same pointer type* is safe. You'll need a `reinterpret_cast` for each conversion.

**You generally don't want to do this** if you can avoid it. Use the original pointer type where possible. Types are good!

Comment: Wouldnt uintptr make more sense

Comment: @CamelToe: Probably :) Depends what the OP's going to do with it, I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`reinterpret_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast) to store a pointer into a [`std::intptr_t` or `std::uintptr_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer), and retrieve it back. This is only defined to convert from- and back to the exact same pointer type, and the `[u]intptr_t`'s value is implementation-defined.